# Does jQuery have something similar to YUI's getDocumentScrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

Does jQuery have something similar to YUI's getDocumentScrollTop?

(reference: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

I gave them both a try on a document with a really, really tall div and they seemed to be equivalent at various scroll points on the screen.